# Put URLs from string into array using regex (problem with trailing period)

Tags: php, regex, url

I am trying to write a function that pulls all url's from a string and remove a potential trailing slash from the end.

```
function getUrls($string) {
    $regex = '/https?\:\/\/[^\" ]+/i';
    preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
    return ($matches[0]);
}
```

But that returns http://test.com. (trailing period) If i have

```
$string = "Hi I am sharing http://test.com.";
$urls = getUrls($string);
```

It returns the URL with the period at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one seems to work (taken from [here](http://myphpform.com/validating-url-email.php))

```
$regex="/(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i";
```

Comment: Thanks! That does work. Any idea on how to make it match with or without http:// ?

Comment: Making it match urls without `http` is risky.. Consider the following string: `this is a comment.net is great.`, it would incorrectly match `comment.net` as a url. I recommend reading the pages linked by martineno, there is some discussion about this problem in Alan Storm's page.

Comment: That actually wasn't working correctly, so I finally found a solution: http://yellow5.us/journal/server_side_text_linkification/

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this, here is what I put together:

```
$aProtocols = array('http:\/\/', 'https:\/\/', 'ftp:\/\/', 'news:\/\/', 'nntp:\/\/', 'telnet:\/\/', 'irc:\/\/', 'mms:\/\/', 'ed2k:\/\/', 'xmpp:', 'mailto:');
$aSubdomains = array('www'=>'http://', 'ftp'=>'ftp://', 'irc'=>'irc://', 'jabber'=>'xmpp:');
$sRELinks = '/(?:(' . implode('|', $aProtocols) . ')[^\^\[\]{}|\\"\'<>`\s]*[^!@\^()\[\]{}|\\:;"\',.?<>`\s])|(?:(?:(?:(?:[^@:<>(){}`\'"\/\[\]\s]+:)?[^@:<>(){}`\'"\/\[\]\s]+@)?(' . implode('|', array_keys($aSubdomains)) . ')\.(?:[^`~!@#$%^&*()_=+\[{\]}\\|;:\'",<.>\/?\s]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}(?:[\/#?](?:[^\^\[\]{}|\\"\'<>`\s]*[^!@\^()\[\]{}|\\:;"\',.?<>`\s])?)?)|(?:(?:[^@:<>(){}`\'"\/\[\]\s]+@)?((?:(?:(?:(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))(?:\.(?:(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))){3})|(?:[A-Fa-f0-9:]{16,39}))|(?:(?:[^`~!@#$%^&*()_=+\[{\]}\\|;:\'",<.>\/?\s]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}))\/(?:[^\^\[\]{}|\\"\'<>`\s]*[^!@\^()\[\]{}|\\:;"\',.?<>`\s](?:[#?](?:[^\^\[\]{}|\\"\'<>`\s]*[^!@\^()\[\]{}|\\:;"\',.?<>`\s])?)?)?)|(?:[^@:<>(){}`\'"\/\[\]\s]+:[^@:<>(){}`\'"\/\[\]\s]+@((?:(?:(?:(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))(?:\.(?:(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))){3})|(?:[A-Fa-f0-9:]{16,39}))|(?:(?:[^`~!@#$%^&*()_=+\[{\]}\\|;:\'",<.>\/?\s]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}))(?:\/(?:(?:[^\^\[\]{}|\\"\'<>`\s]*[^!@\^()\[\]{}|\\:;"\',.?<>`\s])?)?)?(?:[#?](?:[^\^\[\]{}|\\"\'<>`\s]*[^!@\^()\[\]{}|\\:;"\',.?<>`\s])?)?))|([^@:<>(){}`\'"\/\[\]\s]+@(?:(?:(?:[^`~!@#$%^&*()_=+\[{\]}\\|;:\'",<.>\/?\s]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6})|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))(?:\.(?:(?:[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:25[0-5]))){3})|(?:[A-Fa-f0-9:]{16,39}))))(?:[^\^*\[\]{}|\\"<>\/`\s]+[^!@\^()\[\]{}|\\:;"\',.?<>`\s])?)/i';

function getUrls($string) {
    global $sRELinks;
    preg_match_all($sRELinks, $string, $matches);
    return ($matches[0]);
}
```

From http://yellow5.us/journal/server_side_text_linkification/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how strict you want to be, consider the [Liberal, Accurate Regex Pattern for Matching URLs](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls) regular expression pattern discussed on Daring Fireball. The pattern in full is:

```
\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))
```

If you are interested in how it works, Alan Storm has a great [explanation](http://alanstorm.com/url_regex_explained).

Comment: @David: He’s updated his pattern [here](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls). He also points out that not everybody supports `[[:punct:]]`. Me, I’d be more liketo to use `[\pP\pS]` instead. He also includes a version that works only for http and https.