# Regex for urls without http, https, ftp

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex that accept urls like these:

```
http://www.example.com
www.example.com
```

This is what I have so far, but it regex doesn't match URLs without `http://` or `https://`, or `ftp://`:

```
regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
```

How can I make the protocol optional?

Comment: `example.pl`: A website in Poland or a Perl script?

Comment: In the OP's case unfortunately not. It will either be consumed by the regex or not. [RFC 3986](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html#regexp) (the link leads to a regexp to parse URLs) has its reasons to enforce either a scheme or the `\\` part. Although I understand the need to find such stuff (see [the Linkification addon for FF](http://yellow5.us/firefox/linkification/))

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252778/put-urls-from-string-into-array-using-regex-problem-with-trailing-period/4252806#4252806 for a very generic solution.

Comment: [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make the `(ftp|http|https):\/\/` part optional:

```
((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?
```

Comment: Thank you but now I can match for example "example" or "example@example.com". And I don't want it. So how can I solve this?

My regex:
regexp = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
I dont't want to match "example@example.com" or "example"

Comment: `example@example.com` is actually a valid URL: The first `example` is a username, that can be submitted this way. Try loading this very page with an added `example@` between `http://` and `stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: I don't want to accept @ in my urls. Do you know how I can change my regex?

Answer (score 4):

Try this this will validate url with (http,ftp,https) or without(http,ftp,https)..

```
/^(?:(ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-z]{3,6}$/;
```

Comment: This regex do not accept url for domains from germany. e.g (www.germany.de). You have to change the regex to     `/^(?:(ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/;` The 2 is important.

Comment: This is not such a great way to do this. Really all you can do is check for a `.`. There are a lot of new TLDs with names longer than 6 chars...

Comment: TLDs can be between 2 and (currently the longest TLD is) 24 characters long (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238640/how-long-can-a-tld-possibly-be/9239264).
`/^(?:(ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,24}$/`

Answer (score 4):

Try this this will validate url with or without(http,ftp,https) in upper and lower cases and also allows you to for numerics

```
/^(?:(ftp|http|https)?:\/\/)?(?:[\w-]+\.)+([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){2,6}$/gi;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the next reg:
`^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$`

Here is an example: https://www.regextester.com/93652

Answer (score 1):

Kindly see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/480/6593

Quoting from the above link:

```
value = 'www.google.com';
if(/(^|\s)((https?:\/\/)?[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+\.?(:\d+)?(\/\S*)?)/gi.test(value)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

regex accept url without http or https

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@%_\+.~#?&//=]*)
```

In HTML5

```
<input pattern="[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@%_\+.~#?&//=]*)" type="text>
```