# JavaScript to remove whatever is after the tld and before the whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bunch of functions that are filtering a page down to the domains that are attached to email addresses. It's all working great except for one small thing, some of the links are coming out like this:

> EXAMPLE.COM
>       EXAMPLE.ORG.
>       EXAMPLE.ORG>.
>       EXAMPLE.COM"
>       EXAMPLE.COM".
>       EXAMPLE.COM).
>       EXAMPLE.COM(COMMENT)"
>       DEPT.EXAMPLE.COM
>       EXAMPLE.ORG
>       EXAMPLE.COM.

I want to figure out one last filter (regex or not) that will remove everything after the TLD. All of these items are in an array.

**EDIT**

The function I'm using:

```
function filterByDomain(array) {
    var regex = new RegExp("([^.\n]+\.[a-z]{2,6}\b)", 'gi');
    return array.filter(function(text){
        return regex.test(text);
    });
}
```

Comment: I'd do it like this, `(.+)\.[\w]`. This will search till the last period with a word character after it. This will keep the second level domain in foreign domains though, for example `ac.uk`, the `ac` would remain.

Comment: @mascaliente: I have provided an update to my answer based on your edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use this regex to match your TLD for each case:

```
/^[^.\n]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$/gim
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT9eQ1/2)

You validation function can be:

```
function filterByDomain(array) {
    var regex = /^[^.\n]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$/gim;
    return array.filter(function(text){
        return regex.test(text);
    });
}
```

**PS:** Do read this [Q & A to see that up to 63 characters are allowed in TLD.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238640/how-long-can-a-tld-possibly-be)

Comment: For some reason the `\b` is breaking my code. I'm updating my question with the function I'm using

Comment: Oh don't use `RegExp` constructor (that requires `\\b` btw). Just use `var regex = /([^.\n]+\.[a-z]{2,3}\b)/gi`

Comment: Please note that a dot after the TLD is actually a valid (and strictly speaking, required) part of a FQDN.

Comment: `.[a-z]{2,3}` is not a good idea: there is `.info` and even generic TLDs

Comment: After your edit, you just substituted the `{2,6}` range in the OP question for `{2,5}`. Are you absolutely certain that this answers the question, sir?

Comment: Are you sure you have read the [original question posted](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30547948/2) which my answer was based upon. Now coming back to TLDs it seems even 6 is not enough and [they allow up to 63 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238640/how-long-can-a-tld-possibly-be).

Answer (score 0):

I'd match all leading `[\w.]` and omit the last dot, if any:

```
var result = url.match(/^[\w\.]+/).join("");
if(result.slice(-1)==".") result = result.slice(0,-1);
```

With note that `\w` should be replaced for something more sophisticated:

- `_` is part of `\w` set but should not be in url path
- `-` is not part of `\w` but can be in url not adjacent to `.` or `-`

To keep the regexp simple and the code readable, I'd do it this way

1. substitute `_` for `#` in url (both `#` and `_` can be only after TLD)
2. substitute `-` for `_` (`_` is part of `\w`)
3. after the regexp test, substitute `_` back for `-`

URL like `www.-example-.com` would still pass, can be detected by searching for `[.-]{2,}`