# Email fixed validation with regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on email validations using regular expressions, where I need some fixed email values to validate before proceeding

Here is a clear requirement

**User can only have up to 50 character before the Octets (@) and a maximum of 25 characters after the Octets, with a total of 80 characters**

I used normal regex to validate email like

```
let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
```

And now for the above requirement I am trying to create an expression like

```
let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?(\w{2,50})+)*@(\w{2,25})+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
```

But it's taking only starting character(*not accepting lower than two*) and not the last number of requirement, So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match 1-50 word chars before the @ *(so no `.` or `-`)* and 1-25 word chars after the @ *(also no `.` or `-`)* and a total of no more than 80 chars:

```
^(?!.{81})(?:\w+[.-])*\w{1,50}@\w{1,25}(?:[.-]\w+)*\.\w{2,3}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.{81})` Negative lookahead, assert that from the current position there are not 81 chars directly to the right
- `(?:\w+[.-])*` Repeat 0+ times 1+ word chars and either a `.` or `-`
- `\w{1,50}` Match 1-50 word chars
- `@` Match literally
- `\w{1,25}` Match 1-25 word chars
- `(?:[.-]\w+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching either a `.` or `-` and 1+ word chars
- `\.\w{2,3}` Match a `.` and 2-3 word chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gAo9AY/1)

Comment: a little bit optimized your solution   ```^(?!.{81})[\w.-]{1,50}@[\w.-]{1,25}\.[a-z]{2,24}$```  check online [here](https://regex101.com/r/y5hy2G/1)  according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238640/how-long-can-a-tld-possibly-be) information, last part of domain name is currently 24 characters max

Comment: Thank you so much for this quick response.